# Multi tenancy with Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor

I need to implement multi-tenancy and i like the way it is solved [here](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/11/multi-tenancy-part-2-components-and.html).

The problem implementing this scenario (in my project) is that the following code snippet

```
var handlerSelectors = windsorContainer.ResolveAll<IHandlerSelector>();
```

gives me something ( {Castle.MicroKernel.IHandlerSelector[0]}).
The following snippet should iterate through handlerSelectors but it's doing nothing !!

```
foreach (var handlerSelector in handlerSelectors)
            {
                windsorContainer.Kernel.AddHandlerSelector(handlerSelector);
            }
```

In the debugger i can see i tries to set a value to var handlerSelector but it skips the for loop.
Am i missing something??

Thanks in advance

Comment: you probably forgot to register HostBasedComponentSelector

Comment: i don't follow...it is stated in web.config as a component. Shouldn't the ResolveAll<IHandlerSelector>() call actually do what it should do:resolve???
..or am i missing something deeper?

Comment: can you do a Resolve<IHandlerSelector>() without any exceptions? if there is any exception then post it here please.

Comment: I indeed get an error:
Can't create component 'urlbased.handlerselector' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
urlbased.handlerselector is waiting for the following dependencies:

Keys (components with specific keys)
- selectableTypes which was not registered.

Comment: there's a typo in the article, it says paramters instead of parameters

Comment: You 're right! 
But how is that possible,... i mean not getting any error report!? Can i define in a <component> section whatever i like? Is this the reason not getting any error?

Comment: Yes, you can define anything within a <component>, sometimes it's very convenient but I agree with you that it could be more strict by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mauricio Sheffer pointed me out how to correct the error! (see comments...or should i say i need a good pair of glasses?)